# Default Insert INTO value for date column while copying row, how to?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, insert, default

Good evening,

I made a well working function with php, mysql and ajax. A link executes a query to copy a entry. This query is currently successfully executed

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO players(day, name, lastname ) SELECT day, name, lastname FROM players WHERE id=$id"; mysql_query( $sql);
```

the column 'day' is the date column. Instead of the date that belongs to the row, I want to insert the current date ($now). Sort of default value, couldn't find anything like this so far. Probably simple, any advice ?:)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include things in a SELECT list that aren't columns. The current date should be available as `current_date` so this SQL should do the trick:

```
insert into players (day, name, lastname)
select current_date, name, lastname
from players
where id = $id
```

If you happen to have the date you wanted in the PHP variable `$this_date` and it was in the right format, then you could use this:

```
insert into players (day, name, lastname)
select '$this_date', name, lastname 
from players
where id = $id
```

Comment: awesome, that worked nicely! now the only problem is, I have to save it formatted as "Thursday 10th November" (l jS F), is this possible?    Cheers!

Comment: Save it as a DATE datatype, not formatted as a string.  Then when you query it, you can format it how you want with [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: @Maarten: So `day` is a string rather than a date? I wouldn't recommend that but you could use [`date_format`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format): `date_format(current_date, '%W %D %M')`.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your time sir :) Works wonderfully! Good day!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin MySQL Date and Now or CURDATE functions. If the column is a DateTime then just use NOW(). [MySQL NOW Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO players(day, name, lastname ) SELECT NOW(), name, lastname FROM players WHERE id=$id"; mysql_query( $sql);
```

If the column is a Date then use the DATE() function with NOW() inside or even easier the CURDATE() function.
[MySQL CURDate Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate)

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO players(day, name, lastname ) SELECT CURDATE(), name, lastname FROM players WHERE id=$id"; mysql_query( $sql);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO players(day, name, lastname ) SELECT DATE(NOW()), name, lastname FROM players WHERE id=$id"; mysql_query( $sql);
```

[MySQL Date Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: I have fixed my mistake. It has been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL has getdate() for the same.